# How to set time logout in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

one user login in attendance that user can logout only in after 8 hours.

How should code in MVC Jquery.

```
var usrtime = ctx.Attendances.Select(s => s.Time && s.Id == Id);
```

This way i get user login time.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (logoutTime > usrtime) {
   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")';
}
```

then in the action log the user out and redirect them to login

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your scenario in a better way. A user logout depends on cookie expiration or token expiration or other ways. Control timeout time of cookie.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="480" />
</authentication>
```